# Show a contact in Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, contacts

I was wondering how to display a contact in Applescript. Basically, I need to open Contacts and then open up the contact I want. I don't know the syntax for Contacts.

Basically, all I have is

```
tell application "Contacts"
activate
end tell
```

So, yeah. Basically nothing lol. I also tried:

```
tell application "Contacts"
set theContact to "Jason Wells"
open person theContact
end tell
```

But, that didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacts is a bit odd—and in my case, at least, seems to have a bit of a bug.

If Contacts is open, it displays its window; if you close the window, it closes the application. Which means that as long as you select the person you want, that person will display.

So this should get you going:

```
--AppleScript seems to need Address Book as the application name
--it will rename it to Contacts on save or compile.
tell application "Address Book"
    activate
    set theContact to the first person whose name is "Jerold Stratton"
    --first group appears to be "card".
    set theGroup to second item of groups of theContact

    --first, move to a group that contains this contact
    set selected of theGroup to true

    --second, select the contact
    set selection to theContact
end tell
```

Now, in my case there is a bug: the application is called Contacts, but AppleScript won’t find it named Contacts. It will find it named “Address Book”. It will then rename it to Contacts, which means that the next time you edit your script while Contacts is closed, it won’t be able to find the application or its terminology, until you edit it back from Contacts to Address Book. This is on OS X 10.9.4.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jerry Stratton's post on this page, I was able to break it down to a single line of code:

```
tell application "Contacts" to set selection to person "Firstname Lastname"
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening the dictionary for Contacts and see that a contact card is a 'person' object. You can see all the properties of a person with:

```
tell app "Contacts" to get properties of person 1
```

To get the person you're looking for, you can do something like:

```
tell application "Contacts" to set p to first person whose (first name is "Jason" and last name is "Wells")
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer was also helpful.